# Backendless CodeRunner not registering with backendless servers

Tags: java, backendless, coderunner

I'm using Backendless to handle data and push notifications for an iOS app. I am currently trying to write the server side code for a timer in Java.

I have followed the guide [here](https://backendless.com/feature-111-coderunner-custom-business-logic-utility/) to download the timer code, open it and build it in IntelliJ IDEA and then run CodeRunner through the terminal.

This is the only output I get from CodeRunner:

```
[INFO] JDK from "JAVA_HOME" - /Library/Java/Home
[INFO] CodeRunner(tm) Backendless Debugging Utility
[INFO] Copyright(C) 2018 Backendless Corp. All rights reserved. 
[INFO] Version: 4.4.7 Build date: 2018-05-14T13:42:44Z
[INFO] CodeRunner session is running for 2 hours and will be terminated on 09:38:39.755[UTC]
```

It never seems to get to the registering step. There is a whole heap of output before the codeRunner version etc, stuff like

```
07:38:39,284 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
07:38:39,284 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
```

Not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get CodeRunner up and running, no pun intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem since 2 hours. I tested it in a sample project 2 weeks ago and it worked fine. Now I'm using it in a real App, it can't register the CodeRunner.

The reason is the CodeRunner.jar build 2018-05-14 seems to have a bug. I replace the old CodeRunner.jar and weborb.jar from the sample project (build 2018-05-02) inside the `bin` directory and it works fine now. Here's the [2 JAR Files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1g8g0e_xYVvlpHOYecY1ipE3_n0pxzLST) in my Google Drive. I replaced both cause I'm not sure where the bug is.

Comment: Thanks very much for the old Jar files, they work fine. You're right, looks like a bug in the latest build

Answer (score 0):

The blog post you linked is for the deprecated version 3 of Backendless (you should have noticed that the console now looks very different from the screenshots). Though the process is mostly the same as described in this blog post, [this documentation for current version](https://backendless.com/docs/bl-java/doc.html#bl_overview) is much more relevant. There is a [quick-start guide](https://backendless.com/docs/bl-java/doc.html#bl_eventhandlers_getting_started_java) there for event handlers, the process for [timers](https://backendless.com/docs/bl-java/doc.html#dynanchor3) is analogous.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, as far as I can see the process is identical to the tutorial which I linked. Please correct me if I’m wrong

Comment: It is mostly, do you use version 4 or 3?

Comment: I use version 4. I downloaded CodeRunner and my timer code directly from the Backendless console